# C++Winrt how to throw and handle exception without terminating program

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt, wil

I have following code

```
IAsyncOperation<bool> trythiswork()
    {
        bool contentFound{ false };
        try
        {
            auto result = co_await someAsyncFunc();
            winrt::check_bool(result)
            if (result)
            {
                contentFound = true;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            LOG_CAUGHT_EXCEPTION();
        }
        co_return contentFound;
    }
```

When the result is false, it fails and throws but catch goes to fail fast and program terminates. How does log function terminate the program? Isn't it supposed to only log the exception? I assumed that I am handling this exception so program won't crash but it is crashing.
So how to throw and catch so that program does not terminate? I do want to throw. And also catch and preferably log the exception as well.
Thanks

Comment: There's no `co_return`. Is that an oversight? Also, we don't know what `LOG_CAUGHT_EXCEPTION()` is, so if that terminates the process, it would help to know what it is. Though given your recent question history, I'm no sure that what you are asking about is actually going to solve your immediate problem.

Comment: co_return was an oversight, I have corrected it. LOG_CAUGHT_EXCEPTION is from here https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/3234003fe96a02a9c1b686cf51f43ee5d3ec5c84/include/wil/result_macros.h#L836
This question is not related to my question about DeleteAsync. Here I tried the above code, and it terminates my program which I do not want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue can be reproduced using the following code:

```cpp
IAsyncOperation<bool> someAsyncFunc() { co_return false; }

IAsyncOperation<bool> trythiswork()
{
    auto contentFound { false };
    try
    {
        auto result = co_await someAsyncFunc();
        winrt::check_bool(result);
        // throw std::bad_alloc {};
        contentFound = true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LOG_CAUGHT_EXCEPTION();
    }
    co_return contentFound;
}

int main()
{
    init_apartment();
    auto result = trythiswork().get();
}
```

As it turns out, everything works as advertised, even if not as intended. When running the code with a debugger attached you will see the following debug output:

> The exception %s (0x    [trythiswork]

Not very helpful, but it shows that logging itself works. This is followed up by something like

> FailFast(1) tid(b230) 8007023E {Application Error}

causing the process to terminate. The WIL only recognizes exceptions of type `std::exception`, `wil::ResultException`, and `Platform::Exception^`. When it handles an unrecognized exception type it will terminate the process by default. This can be verified by commenting out the call to `check_bool` and instead throwing a standard exception (such as `std::bad_alloc`). This produces a program that will log exception details, but continue to execute.

The behavior can be customized by registering a callback for [custom exception types](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-customization#custom-exception-types), giving clients control over translating between custom exception types and `HRESULT` values. This is useful in cases where WIL needs to interoperate with external library code that uses its own exception types.

For C++/WinRT exception types (based on [`hresult_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-error)) the WIL already provides error handling helpers that can be enabled (see [Integrating with C++/WinRT](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-helpers#integrating-with-cwinrt)). To opt into this all you need to do is to `#include <wil/cppwinrt.h>` before **any** C++/WinRT headers. When using precompiled headers that's where the `#include` directive should go.

With that change, the program now works as desired: It logs exception information for exceptions that originate from C++/WinRT, and continues to execute after the exception has been handled.